# Using Redux.createStore with Immutable throws "reducer is not a function (How to use Redux with Immutable.js ans composeEnhancers)

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js, redux-immutable

I wrote this code to create Redux `store`:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux-immutable'

const MyAppReducers = combineReducers({
    Node1: Node1Reducer,
    Node2: Node2Reducer,
    Node3: Node3Reducer,
    Node4: Node4Reducer
})

let store = createStore(
    MyAppReducers,
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(
            thunkMiddleware,
            ApiMiddleware,
            loggerMiddleware
        )
    )
)
```

The result of this configuration is a plain object with inside the `Immutable.Map()`s:

```
{
    Node1: Immutable.Map(),
    Node2: Immutable.Map(),
    Node3: Immutable.Map(),
    Node4: Immutable.Map()
}
```

I want, instead, that all the state tree is an `Immutable.Map()`.

So I tried to pass to `combineReducers()` directly an `Immutable.Map()` object:

```
const MyAppReducers = combineReducers(Immutable.Map({
    Node1: Node1Reducer,
    Node2: Node2Reducer,
    Node3: Node3Reducer,
    Node4: Node4Reducer
}))
```

But this throws an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: reducer is not a function
>
> at combineReducers.js:39
>
> at Array.forEach ()
>
> at combineReducers.js:36
>
> at Map.withMutations (immutable.js:1353)
>
> at combineReducers.js:35
>
> at computeNextEntry (:2:27469)
>
> at recomputeStates (:2:27769)
>
> at :2:31382
>
> at dispatch (createStore.js:165)
>
> at createStore (createStore.js:240)

The documentation of `redux-immutable` states that I should pass the `initialState` as a second argument of the `createStore` function, but my second argument is currently the `composeEnhancers` function that I need to configure middlewares and other things.

**How can I make the entire state tree be an `Immutable.Map()` object?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built-in `combineReducers` function expects that the state it sees is a plain Javascript object.

If you want the state tree to be an `Immutable.js` `Map` instead, you need to use a different function, like the one provided by [`redux-immutable`](https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable) or [other Redux/immutable interop libs](https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md#immutableredux-interop).

Note that the Redux `createStore` function can either be called as:

```
createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composedEnhancers);
createStore(rootReducer, composedEnhancers);
```

So, pass your initial `Immutable.js` `Map` as the second argument.

Comment: Apologies, missed that.  Updated my answer.

Comment: I've tried to pass the initial state to `createStore` but it causes anyway an error about unknown properties: Unexpected property "StateRoot" found in previous state received by the reducer. Expected to find one of the known reducer property names instead: "size", "_root", "__ownerID", "__hash", "__altered". Unexpected properties will be ignored.

And anyway there is the error "Uncaught TypeError: reducer is not a function".

Please, can you expand your answer providing me with some more code as I'm not abe to fix with the current suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just for someone who may have the same problem, the full solution is this:

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux-immutable'
import {fromJS} from 'immutable'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ThunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import {createLogger} from 'redux-logger'

const MyAppInitialState = fromJS({
    Node1: {
        entities: {},
        ui: {}
    },
    Node2: {
        entities: {},
        ui: {}
    },
    Node3: {
        entities: {},
        ui: {}
    },
    Node4: {
        entities: {},
        ui: {}
    }
})

const MyAppReducers = combineReducers({
    Node1: Node1Reducer,
    Node2: Node2Reducer,
    Node3: Node3Reducer,
    Node4: Node4Reducer
})

const LoggerMiddleware = createLogger()

const store = createStore(
    MyAppReducers,
    MyAppInitialState,
    composeEnhancers(
        applyMiddleware(
            thunkMiddleware,
            ApiMiddleware,
            loggerMiddleware
        )
    )
)

// Example of a reducer (just for completeness)
const Node1Reducer = (state = fromJS({entities: {}, ui: {}}), action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        ...
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

With this configuration I'm now able to use `Immutable.js` with `Redux` having the entire `state` as an `Immutable` tree.